# Inconsistent Rendering issue with Trinidad JSF

Tags: rendering, jsf-1.2, trinidad

I am getting rendering error inconsistently in JSF pages. I am using Trinidad Framework.

Following is the log, Please help

```
[6/28/12 11:44:56:124 IST] 00000020 FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I: Document cells/DHZVYYR1Node01Cell/applications/project-ear.ear/deployments/project-ear/META-INF/ibm-application-runtime.props is modified.
[6/28/12 11:46:42:716 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar!/META-INF/jsf-core.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:42:720 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar!/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:42:728 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar!/META-INF/jsf-ui.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:42:735 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar!/META-INF/jstl-core.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:42:738 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar!/META-INF/jstl-fn.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:42:747 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/trinidad-impl-1.2.9.jar!/META-INF/tr.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:42:748 IST] 00000024 compiler      I   Added Library from: wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ashishagarwal/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/trinidad-impl-1.2.9.jar!/META-INF/trh.taglib.xml
[6/28/12 11:46:43:257 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreDocument[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id0] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Document
[6/28/12 11:46:43:257 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreForm[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id2] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Form
[6/28/12 11:46:43:258 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id4] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:258 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id5] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:258 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id6] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:258 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id7] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:258 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id9] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:259 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id10] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:259 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id11] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:259 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id13] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:259 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id14] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
[6/28/12 11:46:43:259 IST] 00000024 UIXComponentB W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase _getRendererImpl Could not find renderer for CoreCommandLink[UIXFacesBeanImpl, id=j_id15] rendererType = org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT THE SOLUTION here is the ref link and below is relevant solution
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200707.mbox/%3C71235db40707151015r55fe85a0o354c7e6e446a2515@mail.gmail.com%3E

On 7/15/07, Burghard Britzke  wrote:

> thank you! that was the fault. is there a documentation available how to set
>   up a trinidad jsf application? and how to work with skins?
>
> Am 15.07.2007 um 17:19 schrieb Simon Lessard:
>
> Hmmm,
>
> About trinidad-config.xml, I would not consider it optional since you'll
>   most likely need to use a skin other than simple in a real application.
>   About your error, I think you might be missing the following in your
>   faces-config.xml:

```
<application>

 <default-render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core</default-render-kit-id>
  </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you can follow step by step this [Initial Setup Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/trinidad/trinidad_initialsetupguide.html).

**Dont forget! Required Additions:**

The following additions need to be made to the web application's descriptor to configure Trinidad's resource servlet (which serves stylesheets, scripts, and images at runtime):

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The following additions need to be made to the web application's descriptor to configure Trinidad's filter:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**NOTE:** *The filter-mapping shown above assumes that the standard JSF servlet's servlet-name is specified as "faces" - this may differ depending on user setup, and so should be specified appropriately.*

The following addition needs to be made to the JSF application configuration resource to configure Trinidad's core RenderKit:

```
<application>
  <default-render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core</default-render-kit-id>
</application>
```